# Is it possible to choose a number so that the function is continuous at the origin?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Is it possible to choose a number $\alpha$ so that the function $f : R^{2} \rightarrow R$ with

$f(x,y) = \lbrace \; \frac{(2x - y)^2}{x^2 + y^2}, \;(x,y) \neq (0,0); \\ \qquad \quad \qquad \alpha, \qquad (x,y) = (0,0) \;\rbrace$

is continuous at the origin?

I tried subbing $y=mx$ in but I can't seem to come to any convincing conclusions.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no well defined limit. To show this consider the two paths that approach the origin.

Take $(x(t),y(t)) = (t,0)$. By substituting this in and taking $t\to 0$ we obtain

$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{(2t - 0)^2}{t^2 + 0^2} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{4t^2}{t^2} = 4$$

while on the other hand by taking $(x(t),y(t)) = (t,t)$ we get by taking $t\to 0$ the result

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(2t-t)^2}{t^2 + t^2} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t^2}{2t^2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

and thus we have two paths approaching the origin which give different values. This means that it is not a removable singularity (i.e. no $\alpha$ can be selected to make it continuous at the origin).

Answer (score 2):

Try to compute the limit along the lines $y=2x$ and $y=0$.

For $y=2x$, $f(x,2x)=0 \to 0$ as $x\to 0$.

For $y=0$, $f(x,0)=4 \to 4$ as $x\to 0$.

In order to have continuity at $(0,0)$ the above limits should be equal to $\alpha$, therefore such $\alpha$ does not exist.

P.S. In this case for $y=mx$, $f(x,mx)=(2-m)^2/(m^2+1)$. So you have a infinite choices fo $m$ to prove that the function can not be continuously extended at $(0,0)$.